# rand() and srand() functions in c++

Tags: c++

I have been learning recently how to program games in c++ from a beginner book, and i reached a lesson where i have to make a game in where i have to guess the computer's random picked number, and i have to use this line of code:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
variable=rand();
```

I obviously use iostream cstdlib and ctime.I don't really understand how this works.How is it picking the time and date, and  by what rules is it converting into an unsigned int. Basically, how those functions work.
Thank you!

Comment: Look at the documentation for `srand` and `rand`. In C++11 or later you should use types from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random instead.

Comment: If you look at the [specification of `time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) you'll see that it returns a `time_t`. If you look at the [definition of `time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t), you'll find that it's *almost always* an integral type. In fact I'm not aware of an implementation where it isn't. Thus no problem converting it to a regular `int`.

Comment: P.S. I'm not in agreement that this should be closed as a duplicate, since it's asking more about the interaction between `time` and `srand` rather than rand/srand itself.

Answer (score 9):

## 1. About `time()`

`time` (or better `std::time` in C++) is a function that returns some integer or floating point number that represents the current time in some way.

Which arithmetic type it actually returns and how it represents the current time is unspecified, however, most commonly you will get some integer type that holds the seconds since begin of the Unix epoch.

## 2. About `srand()`

`srand` is a function that uses its argument (which is of type `unsigned int`), the so called *seed*, to set the internal state of the pseudo number generator `rand`. When I write *random* in the rest of this answer, read *pseudo random*.

Using a different seed will in general result in a different sequence of random numbers produced by subsequent calls to `rand`, while using the same seed again will result in the exactly same sequence of random numbers.

## 3. Using `time()` to seed `rand()`

If we do not want to get the same random numbers every time we run the program, we need some seed that is different on each run. The current time is a widely used source for such a seed as it changes constantly.

This integer (or whatever else `time` returned) representing the current time is now converted to `unsigned int` with a `static_cast`. This explicit cast is not actually needed as all arithmetic types convert to `unsigned int` implicitly, but the cast may silence some warnings. As time goes by, we can expect the resulting `unsigned int` and thus the sequence of random numbers produced by `rand` to change.

## 4. Pitfalls

If, as is common, `time` returns the number of seconds since the beginning of the Unix epoch, there are three important things to note:

1. The sequence you produce will be different only if at least a second has passed between two invocations.
2. Depending on the actual implementation, the resulting sequences may start of kind of similar if the time points used to seed `rand` are close to each other (compared to time since Epoch). Afaik, this is the case in MSVC's implementation. <s>If that is problematic, just discard the first couple of hundred or thousand values of the sequence.</s> (As I have learned by now, this does not really help much for poor RNGs as commonly used for `rand`. So if that is problematic, use `<random>` as described below.)
3. Your numbers are not very random in the end: If someone knows when your call to `srand` occurred, they can derive the entire sequence of random numbers from that. This has actually led to a decryption tool for a ransom ware that used `srand(time(0))` to generate its "random" encryption key.

Also, the sequence generated by `rand` tends to have poor statistical properties even if the seed was good. For a toy program like yours, that is probably fine, however, for real world use, one should be aware of that.

## 5. The new `<random>`

C++11 introduced new random number facilities that are in many ways superior to the old `rand` based stuff. They provided in the standard header [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random). It includes [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) which provides a way to get actually random seeds, powerful pseudo random number generators like [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) and facilities to map the resulting random sequences to integer or float ranges without introducing unnecessary bias.

Here is an example how to randomly roll a die in C++11:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
 
    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

(Code from [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)) **Note:** `std::random_device` does not work properly with MinGW, at least in the version (Nuwen MinGW5.3) I tested!

It should also be noted that the state space of a `mt19937` is much larger than the 32 bit we (commonly) get out of a single call to `random_device`. Again, this will most likely not matter for toy programs and homework, but for reference: [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device) is my attempt to properly seed the entire state space, plus some helpful suggestions in the answers.

If you are interested in more details about `rand` vs `<random>`, [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) is an interesting watch.

Answer (score 0):

First line:
srand() is a pseudo-random number generator. In your case it is initialized  with the current time (execution time) on your system. 
Second line:
After the pseudo-random number generator is configured, you can retrieve random numbers by calling rand().